# Correlation based feature selection CFS

Tags: r, feature-selection

The code below represents the implementation of Correlation based feature selection technique applied based on 10 fold cross validation and evaluated by svm classifier How can i used the subset parameter in the svm classifier? any explanation will be appreciated

```
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(FSelector)
data=iris
#split data into train and test
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(data$Cardio1M, p=0.7, list=FALSE)
data_train <- data[ trainIndex,]
data_test <- data[-trainIndex,]
set.seed(10)
subset <- cfs(Species~., data_train)
#Using selected features to train svm
svm_model<-svm(Species~subset,data_train[,subset],cost=.1,kernel="radial")
p<-predict(svm_model,data_test[,-5])
accuracy=mean(p==data_test[,5])
```

Comment: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) minimize the code

Comment: @Prateek done thank you for your comment to improve the question

Comment: Isn't this the same question as asked earlier today? Fast Correlation Filter Selection: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49499527/fast-correlation-filter-selection

Comment: Nope i just cofused on the same code i am going to change it right now but this one implement CFS and the other one another technique as the title FCFS